# Bianchi identity implies 4 of Einstein's equations are constraints

Tags: general-relativity

I've been reading Sean Carroll's [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712019.pdf) on General Relativity, and in his chapter titled "Gravitation" (chapter 4), he expresses the Bianchi identity as $$\partial_{0}G^{0\nu}=-\partial_{i}G^{i\nu}-\Gamma^{\mu}_{\;\mu\lambda}G^{\lambda\nu}-\Gamma^{\nu}_{\;\mu\lambda}G^{\mu\lambda}$$ He observes that the right-hand side does *not* contain any third-order time derivatives, and therefore the left-hand side must not either. As such, four of Einstein's equations $G^{0\nu}$ are simply constraints on the initial data.

What confuses me here, is why is it necessarily true that the left-hand side must not contain any third-order time derivatives?

Is the point that this is an *identity*, and therefore must hold for an arbitrary metric $g_{\mu\nu}$? Of course, there could be some particular cases where the third-order time derivatives of the metric are related, in precisely the right way, to the the second and first-order time derivatives, such that this identity holds. However, this will not be the case in general, and so it must be that there are no third-order time derivatives. Would this reasoning be correct?

Comment: Yes, the point is that this is a mathematical identity, this is second Bianchi identity in a Riemannian manifold with a metric connection without torsion, $ \nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}=0$. So, your left hand side and right hand side are really the "same thing" written in a different way.

Comment: @Charo         Ah ok. So can one view the expression I wrote as "the time derivative of $G^{0\nu}$ is equal to stuff that is, at most, second-order in time derivatives, and therefore $G^{0\nu}$ must be, at most, first-order in time derivatives"?

Comment: Yes, it's that way.